# Convert dynamic string to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm in need of some help converting JSON strings to JSON objects.
Here is my variable:

```
var myString= "{ title: 'mySchema'," + "root: {id:'"  + var1 + "'," + "title:'" + var2  + "'," + "subtitle:'" + var3 + "',";
childrenVar = myString + "{ id: '" + var1 + "'," + "title: '" + var2 + "'," + "subtitle: '" + var3 + "'," + "type: '" +  var4 + "'";

myString= getChildNodes(tasksEntries, head, liststring);
myString= myString + "},";}
myString= myString+ "]}}"; }
myString= childrenVar;
myString= childrenVar;
JSON.stringify(myString);
$.parseJSON(myString);
```

This is `myString` output this when I debug:

```
{title: 'mySchema',
 root: { 
     id:'1',
     title:'oOB', 
     subtitle:'Hang Chaw', 
     children: [
       { 
         id: '2',
         title: 'OaK',
         subtitle: 'Ke Man',
         type: 'VA'
       },
       { 
         id: '3',
         title: 'OOB', 
         subtitle: 'Hung Aslew',
         type: 'VA'
       },
     ]
   }
};
```

Comment: What these lines meaning.....myString= myString+ "]}}"; }
myString= childrenVar;  You're overriding myString value.....Just create proper string and do {var obj = JSON.parse(myString)}

Comment: @Piyuesh `myString = myString + "]}};` is a concatenation statement. He is not overriding the original value.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you are trying to achieve with this code. Are you trying to create JSON from an object? Create an object from JSON? In either case, it's not necessary to do any string processing. Please clarify your question by using the correct terminology. I assume by "JSON string" you mean a string containing JSON, and by "JSON object" a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

remove the last comma before close array ( ] ).

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the object keys as well. A proper JSON string would look something like the string below. [jQuery.parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Here is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9TKv/), where the string is converted to an object, and then logged to the console.

```
var myString = '{"title": "mySchema","root": {"id":"1","title":"oOB","subtitle":"Hang Chaw","children": [{ "id": "2","title": "OaK","subtitle": "Ke Man","type": "VA"},{ "id": "3","title": "OOB","subtitle": "Hung Aslew","type": "VA"}]}}';
```

Here is the same [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9TKv/1/), using JSON.parse. The latest version of JavaScript natively supports JSON. If you are only using jQuery to parse JSON strings, then you should use JSON.parse, and not include the jQuery library.

Comment: use JSON.parse instead of jQuery.parseJSON

Comment: @FUserThrowError The OP's example was using $.parseJSON, which is why my solution did the same. JSON.parse and $.parseJSON have the same affect.